# Going to the end of line shortcut for Visual Studio Code

Tags: shortcut

I need to click some keyboards to go to the end of line now, but how can we go to the end of line easily?

Comment: home / end keys do this

Answer (score 0):

By default I think its <kbd>End</kbd> key.